# What is the metal sheet in front of the engine called on a Cessna 182 or similar?

Tags: terminology, piston-engine, feature-identification, cessna-182

I need to know the name of that metal sheet covering the front of the engine in small Cessnas (specifically the Cessna 182), just behind the propeller. I mean the one where the cowl plugs are put into:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a broken `m` key on your keyboard :) Also do you have a photo perhaps? Did you mean *cowl flaps?*

Comment: Do you mean the cowl(ing)?

Comment: @ymb1 not broken, just some dust ! ;) I have added a picture - the area circled in red is the part I mean.

Comment: @StephenS maybe - I have added a picture.

Comment: Do you mean 1) the sheet that *has* the openings, or 2) the metal sheet in front of the engine but behind the cowl (i.e. the sheet seen *through* the openings)? I thought you meant the second one, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @ymb1 I mean the first one, that one with the holes in it.

Comment: @Programmer: If you're interested in the second, that's the rigid metal sheet part of the [baffle system](https://www.rv8-hangar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/img_3333.jpg) that keeps the air close to the cylinders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forwardmost part of the cowling is called the Nose Bowl.  On most modern airplanes it's made of fiberglass, and attached to the adjacent aluminum of the main cowling with rivets designed for composite to aluminum joints.

On most planes the nose bowl is split in two along with the rest of the cowling, so the upper half is part of the top cowl and the lower half part of the lower cowl. A lot of older airplanes have one piece nose bowls that attach to the main cowl with screws, and you had to remove the propeller to remove the nose bowl itself.

Comment: Give me time to figure out the gag....

Comment: Your sense of humour is actually close to mine lol.